# How to place a point in 3D so that it creates a certain angle?

Tags: c++, math, 3d, rotation, trigonometry

I have a small question about 3D.

What follows is an example of my problem.

I have two points:

A: 12 4 5
B: 6 8 -10

I have another point:
C: 5 6 7

I need to transform(?) point C so that the angle ABC is 48 degrees.

How do I do this? I would appreciate if someone can help me with the formulas or maybe even make the above example into a working one.

Another way to put it: How do I transform C.x, C.y, and C.z so that the angle ABC is 48 degrees?

I would really appreciate some help on this as I am stuck at the moment.

Side note:
I already implemented a method for finding the angle:

```
float Angle( float x1, float y1, float z1,
             float x2, float y2, float z2 )
{
  float x, y, z;
  CrossProduct( x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, &x, &y, &z );

  float result = atan2 ( L2Norm( x, y, z ),
                         DotProduct( x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 ) );

  return result;
}
```

You use it:
Angle( B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y, B.z - A.z,
       C.x - B.x, C.y - B.y, C.z - B.z );

Comment: There are an infinite number of transformations that could do this.

Comment: At the moment they make the angle 25.7663.
I would imagine that I have to transform(?) point C by 22.2337 degrees for C.X, C.Y, C.Z. If this is correct how do I do it?

Comment: How would you solve it for 2D?

Comment: Which 48 degree angle would you like to make?

Comment: Ignacio, If I understand you correctly, there are two 48 degrees with the formula I use to calculate the degrees (-48 and +48). Would the solution to my question differ, in terms of the equations I need to use, depending if I want -48 or +48 degrees? Or I did not understand your question. :)

Comment: One additional point of information you should probably supply is that the point should not leave the plane.  I assume this is the case.  Otherwise, as some others have pointed out, there are more possible answers than you're looking for.

Comment: Since you're working in three dimensions, there are an infinite number of resultant points lying along a cone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       A------C    
       |     
 c''   |    c'
       B
```

As three point in 3D define a plane, there are only 2 possible candidates for a transform C-->c' or C-->c'' at that plane.

c' would be then c' = A+t*(B-A) + u*(C-A) with constraint Normalize(c'-A) dot Normalize(B-A) == cos (48 / 180 * pi).

I'd first suggest normalizing D=(B-A), after that:

```
D dot D+u*(C-A) = 1 * |D+u(C-A)| * cos (48 degrees)

Dx*(Dx+u*(Cx-Ax))+ Dy*(Dy+u*(Cy-Ay))+Dz*(Dz+u*(Cz-Az)) ==
    0.669 * sqrt ((Dx+u*(Cx-Ax))^2+(Dy+u*(Cy-Ay))^2+(Dz+u*(Cz-Az))^2)
```

This is of form  a+u*b == 0.669*sqrt(c+du+e*u^2),  which will be simplified to a second degree polynomial in *u* by squaring both sides.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not really understanding the formula, though. What is t and u?

Would it be possible for you to plug in my example of 3 points into it so that I see how it goes?

Comment: u and t are unknown variables that scale the vectors (B-A) and (C-A) to satisfy the equation of the dot product, which by definition is t(B-A) dot u(C-A) == |t(B-A)|*|u(C-A)|*cos(angle) and where || is the length operator == sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z). You'll fix the angle and see what u and t you'll get.

Comment: You pointed out that t == 1.    

(B-A)dot u(C-A) == sqrt( (B.x-A.x)^2 + (B.y-A.y)^2 + (B.z-A.z)^2 )*    
                  sqrt( u(C.x-A.x)^2 + u(C.y-A.y)^2 + u(C.z-A.z)^2 )  
    
If I use: A: 12 4 5; B: 6 8 -10; C: 5 6 7 then:  
  
(-6, 4, -15) dot u(-7, 2, 2) = sqrt(36 + 16 + 225)*sqrt( 49u + 4u + 4u )  
  
(-6, 4, -15)dot u(-7,2,2) = 16.65*sqrt(u)*7.55  
(-6,4,-15) dot (-7,2,2) = 125.705*sqrt(u)  
  
I am not sure after this.

Comment: The angle between ABC _is_ fixed, but what I meant is that the angle between 1*(B-A) and c', where c' = u*(C-A)+(B-A) is negotiable.

Comment: One more thing: this equation only solves _u_ for a vector going through c', which means that you probably want to scale c' to be of the same length as |C-A|.

Comment: How would I do that? Should I do it by diving it by the length of |C-A| ?

Comment: You normalize c' by dividing by its length and multiply by the length of |C-A|.  It's c' <= |C-A| * c' / |c'|.

Comment: I cannot seem to be able to get the result. I get two roots u1 and u2. Do I plug each in c' = A+t*(B-A) + u*(C-A) ?

Comment: No, just the positive. The interpretation of 'u' is anyway that the resulting vector c' has a component going towards (C-A), not away from it.

Comment: After I get the roots I apply the formula below for each coordinate of new_C:

new_C.X = A.X + (B.X - A.X) + root1 * (C.X - A.X) ............ But when I apply my Angle formula Angle(A, B, new_C), the new angle is not 48 degrees.

Comment: I mean I use it like this: Angle( A - B, A - new_C )

Comment: I have no idea, what L2Norm means, but with acos((c-a)/|c-a| dot (b-a)/|b-a|) the angle of the original set is about 80.84 degrees. Do you confirm? Anyway, taking a cross product of (c-a),(b-a) results a vector that is perpendicular to both -- that vector is no longer in the same plane.

Comment: I set this to answered. Will continue in the other thread. I posted the angle I get there. Hope to see you there!

Answer (score 1):

The track of point C is actually a cone, you can imagine, B is the vertex and line AB is the central line of the cone, means the 3D cone is symmetric on AB.

Comment: I upvoted, but this answer would be more complete if you could find an equation for that cone, or even if you could find the point closest to point C on that cone.

Comment: Also note that point C is one point, given as input, with known coordinates. The cone is the set of all possible points for the transformed image. The transformed image will not be named point C, since there is already a point named C. So your first sentence "The track of point C is actually a cone" is a bit clumsily-worded.