# Quaternion and axis of rotation

Tags: c++, math, 3d, rotation, quaternions

This question has been answered. Below is most of the code that you need to make it work! Hope it helps others.

Thanks to @Aki Suihkonen, @David Hammen, and @MBo.

Both Angle functions give the right answer.

I have three points:

```
A: 12 4 5
B: 6 8 -10
C: 5 6 7
```

I have implemented quaternions. I want to rotate point C so that Angle( A, B, C ) would be 40 degrees higher than before.

My question is: According to which axis do I have to rotate? I imagined that because A,B, and C create a plane I have to rotate point C according to the perpendicular axis to the vectors BA and BC. I obtained it with the CrossProduct of their unit vectors but when I try to get the Angle( A, B, C ) it does not give me the right result.

This is how I get the angle: (The old way)

```
results:
Angle of ABC before rotation = 67.3895.
Angle of ABC after rotation = 107.389.

float Angle( float x1, float y1, float z1,
             float x2, float y2, float z2 )
{
  float x, y, z;
  CrossProduct( x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, &x, &y, &z );

  float result = atan2 ( L2Norm( x, y, z ),
                         DotProduct( x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 ) );

  return result;
}
```

Where the x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 are the results from the unit vectors B-A and B-C.

Updated angle function:

```
results:
Angle of ABC before rotation = 67.3895.
Angle of ABC after rotation = 107.389.

Angle( Atom &atom1, Atom &atom2, Atom &atom3 )
{
float px1, py1, pz1;
    float px2, py2, pz2;

    UnitVector( atom1.X(), atom1.Y(), atom1.Z(),
            atom2.X(), atom2.Y(), atom2.Z(),
            &px1, &py1, &pz1 );


    UnitVector( atom3.X(), atom3.Y(), atom3.Z(),
            atom2.X(), atom2.Y(), atom2.Z(),
            &px2, &py2, &pz2 );

  float dot_product = DotProduct( px1, py1, pz1, px2, py2, pz2 );
  float length_BA = sqrt( px1*px1 + py1*py1 + pz1*pz1 );
  float length_BC = sqrt( px2*px2 + py2*py2 + pz2*pz2 );

  return acos( dot_product / ( length_BA * length_BC ) );
}

float DotProduct( float x1, float y1, float z1,
                  float x2, float y2, float z2 )
{
  return x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2;
}

void CrossProduct( float x1, float y1, float z1,
                   float x2, float y2, float z2,
                   float *ox, float *oy, float *oz )
{
  *ox = (y1*z2) -(z1*y2);
  *oy = -((x1*z2) -(z1*x2));
  *oz = (x1*y2) -(y1*x2);
}
```

So my question is: According to which axis do I have to rotate point C so that Angle(A,B,C) would be 40 degrees larger than before?

```
  // The 3 points.
  Atom A( "A", -4, 2 , 8 );
  Atom B( "B", -1, 3 , 4 );
  Atom C( "C", -2, -4 , 5 );

  float x1, y1, z1;
  float x2, y2, z2;
  float x, y, z;

  // Get the cross product. Create the perpendicular vector to the BA and BC vectors.
  PointVector( A.X(), A.Y(), A.Z(), B.X(), B.Y(), B.Z(), &x1, &y1, &z1 );
  PointVector( C.X(), C.Y(), C.Z(), B.X(), B.Y(), B.Z(), &x2, &y2, &z2 );

  CrossProduct( x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, &x, &y, &z );

  // Normalize the coordinates.
  float length = sqrt( x*x + y*y + z*z );
  length = 1.0 / length;

  x *= length;
  y *= length;
  z *= length;

  // Create the 40 degrees angle. It is supposed to increment the current ABC angle by 40 degrees.
  float angle = 40*M_PI/180;
  float sinAngleOver2 = sin(angle/2);
  float w = cos(angle/2);

  // Create the axis quat.
  Quatd q(w, x * sinAngleOver2, y * sinAngleOver2, z * sinAngleOver2);

  // Create the point quaternal. The angle of it equals to the current ABC angle.
  angle = Angle( A, B, C ) *180/M_PI;
  angle *= M_PI/180;
  sinAngleOver2 = sin(angle/2);
  w = cos(angle/2);

  // Normalize the coordinates. The coordinates are the C point coordinates.


    x = C.X() - B.X();
    y = C.Y() - B.Y();
    z = C.Z() - B.Z();

    length = sqrt( x*x + y*y + z*z );
    length = 1.0 / length;

    x *= length;
    y *= length;
    z *= length;


  Quatd qpt(w, x * sinAngleOver2, y * sinAngleOver2, z * sinAngleOver2);

  // Rotate.
  qpt = q*qpt*q.unitInverse();

  Atom new_C;
  new_C.X( qpt.x + B.X() );
  new_C.Y( qpt.y + B.Y() );
  new_C.Z( qpt.z + B.Z() );

  cout << "Angle: " << Angle( A, B, new_C )*180/M_PI << '\n';
```

Comment: Are you making a note about the angle algorithm or do you mean that if I remove the L2Norm I will get my desired result?

Comment: What does function L2Norm do? You can calculate angle as result = arccos(DotProduct( x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 )/ (BA.Length*CA.Length))

Comment: Not sure. The atan2 formula for it was explained like this. I believe I saw it in one of the matlab forums. As for the axis, do you have a solution for it?

Comment: Given the name, I strongly suspect that `L2Norm` calculates the [1=L2 norm] of the input vector. In other words, it calculates the Euclidean length of the vector. [1]http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html

Comment: You didn't show the code for how you are rotating C, so this is just a guess: You are rotating C **about the origin**. That's not what you want to do. You need to rotate C about B.

Comment: Yes, the axis of rotation would be the plane normal, which is the normalized cross-product of the two vectors defining the plane. However, as suggested by MBo (and myself in your other thread), your Angle function might need revising. It gives 89.926, while the arccos gives 80.841 (degrees).

Comment: I will revise the angle function and see if it works. Thank you for the help so far @Aki. I would give you 1000 points if I could. :) I more thing: Only point C must move. I cannot move the rest. This is like a jigsaw puzzle and point C must be rotated in such a manner as to create a certain angle.

Comment: For those who wonder what L2Norm is: return sqrtf( pow( x, 2 ) + pow( y, 2 ) + pow( z, 2 ) );

Comment: About axis of rotation - yes, your solution with CrossProduct is fine, it is direction vector of this axis. About angle - you are trying to use some 2D-case solution, it's wrong here

Comment: result = arccos(DotProduct( x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 )/ (BA.Length*CA.Length)). Do you mean BA.Length*BC.Length? (If B is the middle point)?

Comment: I mean B-A and C-A, because you have used "vectors B-A and C-A", and I thought about A as rotation point. Forget about denominator if you use unit vectors.

Comment: I just tested with the above function. The Angle( A, B, C ), with middle point B, is 67.3895. When I rotate point C I get 75.4952. I believe the error is somewhere in the code I just inserted in my main post.

Comment: I updated to reflect: Where the x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 are the results from the unit vectors B-A and B-C.

Comment: Updated the main post with more code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place a point in 3D so that it creates a certain angle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472287/how-to-place-a-point-in-3d-so-that-it-creates-a-certain-angle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

```
// Normalize the coordinates. The coordinates are the C point coordinates.
length = sqrt( C.X()*C.X() + C.Y()*C.Y() + C.Z()*C.Z() );
length = 1.0 / length;

x = C.X() / length;
y = C.Y() / length;
z = C.Z() / length;
```

You've confused yourself by reusing your `length` variable to store `1 / length`.  You need to multiply the components of `C` by `length` to normalize your vector here.

I'm not familiar enough with quaternion maths to understand what you are trying to do at the end, but it does seem like you are rotating `C` around the origin.  You want to rotate around `B`, which would mean subtracting `B` from `C`, performing your rotation around the origin, and then adding `B` onto the result to get back into your original space.

Personally, I would implement some kind of quaternion-vector multiplication, or convert the quaternion to a matrix in order to perform the transformation.

Comment: Victory! Thank you, so much. It works now. I will update the main post with the right code so that everyone can benefit.

If this was reddit I would give upvotes to everyone!